# exposing the structure of inductively defined terms in coq

Tags: lambda-calculus, coq

The proof that typing derivations are unique in the simply-typed lambda calculus is trivial on paper. The proof that I am familiar with proceeds by complete induction on typing derivations. However, I am having trouble proving that typing derivations, represented *via* the type of typing derivations, are unique. Here, the predicate `dec Γ x τ` is true if the variable `x` has type `τ` in environment `Γ`. The typing predicate `J` is defined as usual, simply reading off the typing rules for the simply-typed lambda calculus:

```
Inductive J (Γ : env) : term → type → Set :=
  | tvar : ∀ x τ, dec Γ x τ → J γ (var x) τ
  | tabs : ∀ τ₁ τ₂ e, J (τ₁ :: γ) e τ₂ → J γ (abs τ₁ e) (arr τ₁ τ₂)
  | tapp : ∀ τ₁ τ₂ e₁ e₂, J γ e₁ (arr τ₁ τ₂) → J γ e₂ τ₁ → J γ (app e₁ e₂) τ₂.
```

I am having trouble exposing the structure of a term of type `J` when proving that typing derivations are unique. For instance, I can induct on either `d1` or `d2` in the following lemma, but cannot induction on `d1` then destruct `d2` and conversely. The error message given by Coq (abstracting over terms leads to a term which is ill-typed) is slightly obscure, and the Coq wiki doesn't provide any help. For reference, this is the lemma that I am trying to prove:

```
Lemma unique_derivation : ∀ Γ e τ (d₁ d₂ : J Γ e τ), d₁ = d₂.
```

I have no problems when inducting on terms, for instance, when proving that the types are unique.

**EDIT:** I added the the minimal number of definitions necessary to state the result that I am having trouble with. In response to huitseeker's comment, the sort of `J` was chosen because I wanted to reason about typing derivations as structured objects in order to perform operations like extraction and prove results like uniqueness, which I haven't done in Coq before.

In response to the first part of the comment, I can perform `induction` on either `d1` or `d2`, but *after* performing `induction` I cannot use `destruct`, `case`, or `induction` on the remaining term. This means that I cannot expose the structure of both `d1` and `d2` in order to reason about both proof trees. The error that I receive when I attempt to do so, says that abstracting over the remaining terms leads to a term which is ill-typed.

```
Require Import Unicode.Utf8.
Require Import Utf8_core.
Require Import List.

Inductive type : Set :=
  | tau : type
  | arr : type → type → type.

Inductive term : Set :=
  | var : nat → term
  | abs : type → term → term
  | app : term → term → term.

Definition dec (Γ : list type) x τ : Prop :=
  nth_error γ x = Some τ.

Inductive J (Γ : list type) : term → type → Set :=
  | tvar : ∀ x τ, dec Γ x τ → J Γ (var x) τ
  | tabs : ∀ τ₁ τ₂ e, J (τ₁ :: Γ) e τ₂ → J Γ (abs τ₁ e) (arr τ₁ τ₂)
  | tapp : ∀ τ₁ τ₂ e₁ e₂, J Γ e₁ (arr τ₁ τ₂) → J Γ e₂ τ₁ → J Γ (app e₁ e₂) τ₂.

Lemma derivations_unique : ∀ Γ e τ (d1 d2 : J Γ e τ), d1 = d2.
Proof. admit. Qed.
```

I've tried experimenting with `dependent induction` and several results from the `Coq.Logic` library, but without success. That derivations are unique seems like it should be an easy proposition to prove.

Comment: Please be a bit more precise what you have tried ('a term which is ill-typed' can have several meanings for your particular problem - is it Coq or you that does the typing?-, you use *destruct* as a verb, but that can mean `case`, `destruct` or something else). Finally, are you sure about the sort of `J` ? Are you familiar with the notion of predicativity ?

Comment: I'm familiar with the notion of predicativity and that `Set` is predicative in Coq. My limited understanding indicates to me that this isn't the problem. I edited the original post to reflect the minimal development necessary to state the theorem, and tried to describe the problem that I'm having in more detail.

Comment: @huitseeker “which is ill-typed” is recognizable as a Coq error, but a copy-paste of the actual proof attempt and exact error message would indeed have been appreciated. Having `J` in `Set` is right if you want to reason about them as first-class objects, say to prove their unicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three problems.

One is the purely technical problem of making the induction work. You can solve the main difficulty with the [`dependent destruction`](http://coq.inria.fr/distrib/V8.4/refman/Reference-Manual011.html#DepInduction) tactic (courtesy of [Matthieu Sozeau on the Coq-Club mailing list](https://sympa.inria.fr/sympa/arc/coq-club/2008-08/msg00000.html)). This is an inversion tactic. I don't pretend to understand how it works under the hood.

A second difficulty is in one of the base cases, for environments. You need to prove that equality proofs in `list nat` are unique; this holds on all decidable domains, and the tools for that are in the [Eqdep_dec](http://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Logic.Eqdep_dec.html) module.

A third difficulty is problem-related. The unicity of derivations does not follow by a direct induction over the term or derivation structure, because your terms do not carry enough type information to reconstruct the derivation. In an application `app e1 e2`, there is no direct way to know the type of the argument. In the simply-typed lambda calculus, type reconstruction does hold, and is easy to prove; in larger calculi (with polymorphism or subtyping) it might not hold (for example, with ML-style polymorphism, there is a unique *principal* type scheme and associated derivation, but there are many derivations using base types).

Here's a quickie proof of your lemma. I omitted the proof of the unicity of environment lookups. You can induct on the term structure or on the derivation structure — this simple proof works because they're the same.

```
Require Import Unicode.Utf8.
Require Import Utf8_core.
Require Import List.
Require Import Program.Equality.

Inductive type : Set :=
  | tau : type
  | arr : type → type → type.

Inductive term : Set :=
  | var : nat → term
  | abs : type → term → term
  | app : term → term → term.

Definition dec (Γ : list type) x τ : Prop :=
  nth_error Γ x = Some τ.

Inductive J (Γ : list type) : term → type → Set :=
  | tvar : ∀ x τ, dec Γ x τ → J Γ (var x) τ
  | tabs : ∀ τ₁ τ₂ e, J (τ₁ :: Γ) e τ₂ → J Γ (abs τ₁ e) (arr τ₁ τ₂)
  | tapp : ∀ τ₁ τ₂ e₁ e₂, J Γ e₁ (arr τ₁ τ₂) → J Γ e₂ τ₁ → J Γ (app e₁ e₂) τ₂.

Lemma unique_variable_type :
  forall G x t1 t2, dec G x t1 -> dec G x t2 -> t1 = t2.
Proof.
  unfold dec; intros.
  assert (value t1 = value t2). congruence.
  inversion H1. reflexivity.
Qed.

Axiom unique_variable_type_derivation :
  forall G x t (d1 d2 : dec G x t), d1 = d2.

Lemma unique_type : forall G e t1 t2 (d1 : J G e t1) (d2 : J G e t2), t1 = t2.
Proof.
  intros G e; generalize dependent G.
  induction e; intros.

  dependent destruction d1. dependent destruction d2.
  apply (unique_variable_type G n); assumption.

  dependent destruction d1. dependent destruction d2.
  firstorder congruence.

  dependent destruction d1. dependent destruction d2.
  assert (arr τ₁ τ₂ = arr τ₁0 τ₂0).
  firstorder congruence.
  congruence.
Qed.

Lemma unique_derivation : forall G e t (d1 d2 : J G e t), d1 = d2.
Proof.
  intros G e; generalize dependent G.
  induction e; intros.

  dependent destruction d1. dependent destruction d2.
  f_equal. solve [apply (unique_variable_type_derivation G n)].

  dependent destruction d1. dependent destruction d2.
  f_equal. solve [apply IHe].

  dependent destruction d1. dependent destruction d2.
  assert (τ₁ = τ₁0). 2: subst τ₁.
  solve [eapply unique_type; eauto].
  f_equal; solve [firstorder].
Qed.
```

Comment: Thank you. It looks like I have some reading about dependent equality to do. Regarding your third comment: I know that typing is unique modulo a principle type scheme for lambda calculi with parametric polymorphism, and so forth. When you say that the proof only works because there is an isomorphism between type and term structure in the simply-typed lambda calculus, do you mean that the structure of the proof would be necessarily different for a calculus with a more expressive type system, even if you were working with a user-defined equivalence instead of Leibniz identity?

Comment: @danportin The proof here works because there's an isomorphism between term and derivation (not type) structure. In general, I would expect to go through an intermediate type reconstruction lemma, which transforms terms into terms with additional type annotations (including the function and argument types on applications). Here the unique typing lemma is enough to progress, but I expect this to quickly become more complicated for “interesting” calculi. I don't have much experience with derivation uniqueness, so take this with a grain of salt.

Comment: Sorry, I means an isomorphism between term structure and typing derivation. Thanks for the information. I wasn't sure if you meant that the structure of the Coq proof worked because of the peculiarity of the simply-typed lambda calculus, and wouldn't work for other lambda calculi. Thank you for clarifying.